# Erro com Template

Tags: c++, template, c++11

Por favor, poderia me ajudar!?

Os erros são para todos os cabeçalhos do arquivo pilha.cpp que faz referência com pilha.h. Envolve uso de Templates.

**Código do pilhas.h:**

```
#ifndef PILHA_H
#define PILHA_H

#include <iostream>
//#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T>
class Pilha{

    T * vetor;
    int tam;
    int topo;

public:
    Pilha(int size);
    ~Pilha();

    void Print();
    void Push(T vetor);
    T Pop();
    T Topo();
    void Limpar();

    bool Vazio();
    bool Cheio();

};

#include "pilha.cpp"

#endif
```

Código do pilhas.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "pilha.h"

//Construtor
template <typename T>
Pilha<T>::Pilha(int size){
    vetor = new T[size];
    this->tam = size;
    topo = -1;
}
//Destrutor: remove o vetor completamente
template <typename T>
Pilha<T>:: ~Pilha(){
    delete [] vetor;
    topo = -1;
}
//Inserindo conteúdo:
template <typename T>
void Pilha<T>::Push(T n){
    if(Cheio())
        std:: cout << "Erro: Pilha cheia" << std::endl;
    else
        this->vetor[++topo] = n;
    //topo++;
}
//Removendo conteúdo;
template <typename T>
T Pilha<T>::Pop(){
    T aux = Topo();
    topo--;
    return aux;
}
//Topo da pilha:
template <typename T>
T Pilha<T>::Topo(){
    if(Vazio())
        std::cout << "Erro: Pilha cheia" << std::endl;
    else
        return vetor[topo];
}
//Limpando a pilha:
template <typename T>
void Pilha<T>::Limpar(){
    delete [] vetor;
    topo = -1;  
}
//Pilha vazia:
template <typename T>
bool Pilha<T>::Vazio(){
    if(topo == -1){
        std::cout << "Pilha vazia" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
//Pilha cheia:
template <typename T>
bool Pilha<T>::Cheio(){
    if(topo == tam - 1){
        std::cout << "Pilha Cheia" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
//Exibindo os elementos da pilha:
template <typename T>
void Pilha<T>::Print(){
    for(int i = topo; i > -1; i--){
        std::cout << vetor[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Tela da compilação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema foi que foi feito o include de um arquivo fonte (cpp), o que resultou em redefinição das funções da classe. Não se pode incluir um arquivo .cpp, apenas cabeçalhos que é o correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A definição das entidades de um template precisam estar na mesma unidade de tradução onde são usadas. A separação de declaração em cabeçalhos e a definição em unidades de tradução não funciona com templates.

O motivo para isso é que o compilador precisa saber como é a definição do template quando o mesmo é instanciado. Se apenas a declaração é visível no ponto de instância, o compilador irá reclamar (como visto nas mensagens de erro do seu compilador.) E não, não tem como o compilador saber a definição da declaração de um template que está separada em outra unidade de tradução, pois não há informação alguma ligando uma a outra (em contraste com código normal, que não é necessário saber a definição de uma função para usá-la.)

Com tudo isso dito, a solução é colocar as definições das sua funções membro dentro do cabeçalho e remover a unidade de tradução.

E, por fim, você está incluindo `"pilha.cpp"` no seu cabeçalho, duplicando as definições.

Comment: Compilou com sucesso logo após excluir a linha --> #include "pilha.cpp", ao final do arquivo pilha.h. Foi a única alteração que fiz. Obrigado!

Comment: @LUIZ, mas não se esqueça de fazer a outra alteração. Assim que você incluir `"pilha.h"` em outra unidade, sem a definição, o código não compilará.

Comment: Só compilou e executou com sucesso o Main.cpp após eu escrever novamente a linha incluindo pilha.cpp, isso após eu ter gerado o arquivo ".o"

Comment: Concluído com sucesso! Removendo a linha #include "pilha.h" no início do arquivo "pilha.cpp". Consegui manter os 3 arquivos.